# C Make own window (GUI) scroll viewer using ScrollWindowEx() wrong content

Tags: c, windows, winapi, window, gdi+

I'm trying to create a window and create own scroll viewer (v-scroll) using `ScrollWindowEx()` in handling the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` window message and it worked but shows me wrong and invalid contents.
My window is a window with `700` width and `600` height and i draw a rectangle with `1000` height and i tried to scroll down the window to see the end of the rectangle but never arrvied to its end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

int SCREEN_SIZE_WIDTH,
        SCREEN_SIZE_HEIGHT;

static unsigned long long GDI_PLUS_TOKEN;
static GdiplusStartupInput GDI_PLUS_STARTUP_INPUT = {
        .GdiplusVersion = 1,
        .SuppressExternalCodecs = FALSE,
        .SuppressBackgroundThread = FALSE };

static WNDCLASSEXW WINDOW_CLASS_DEFAULT = (WNDCLASSEXW) {
        sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW),
        CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW|CS_CLASSDC,
        NULL,
        0,
        16,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        L"MY_CLASS",
        NULL };

LRESULT CALLBACK
window_callback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI
WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
        HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
        PSTR lpCmdLine,
        int nCmdShow) {
    HWND window;
    if((SCREEN_SIZE_WIDTH=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN))==0
       || (SCREEN_SIZE_HEIGHT=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN))==0) {
        printf("GetSystemMetrics() failed.\r\n");
        ExitProcess(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(GdiplusStartup(&GDI_PLUS_TOKEN, &GDI_PLUS_STARTUP_INPUT, NULL)!=Ok) {
        printf("GdiplusStartup() failed.\r\n");
        ExitProcess(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    WINDOW_CLASS_DEFAULT.hInstance=hInstance;
    WINDOW_CLASS_DEFAULT.hbrBackground= CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));
    WINDOW_CLASS_DEFAULT.hCursor=LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    WINDOW_CLASS_DEFAULT.lpfnWndProc=window_callback;
    if(!RegisterClassExW(&WINDOW_CLASS_DEFAULT)) {
        printf("RegisterClassExW() failed.\r\n");
        ExitProcess(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    window=CreateWindowExW(
            0, L"MY_CLASS",
            L"MY PROJECT",
            WS_POPUP|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            ((SCREEN_SIZE_WIDTH - 700) / 2), // Center of the screen
            ((SCREEN_SIZE_HEIGHT - 400) / 2), // Center of the screen
            700, 600, NULL,
            NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if(window==NULL) {
        printf("CreateWindowExA() failed.\r\n");
        goto failure;
    }
    ShowWindow(window, SW_NORMAL);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    UnregisterClassA("DRAWPEN", hInstance);
    ExitProcess(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    failure:
    UnregisterClassA("DRAWPEN", hInstance);
    ExitProcess(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK
window_callback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    static int scroll_value = 0;
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
        {
            // On scroll wheel, let's use ScrollWindowEx() function
            // to scroll vertical only and here is my problem !
            ScrollWindowEx(
                    hwnd, 0, GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam),
                    NULL, NULL, NULL,
                    NULL, SW_INVALIDATE);
            UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        }
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            printf("WM_PAINT\r\n");
            hdc=BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            GpGraphics *gfx;
            GdipCreateFromHDC(hdc, &gfx);
            GpPen *pen;
            GdipCreatePen1(0xFF4c4c4c, 15, UnitPixel, &pen);
            GdipDrawRectangle(gfx, pen, 20, 20, 100, 1000);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**A picture for when the application started.**
[image: A picture for when the application started.]

**A picture for when i scroll down (never arrive at the end of rectangle**

[image: A picture for when i scroll down (never arrive at the end of rectangle)]

**A picture for when i scroll up**

[image: A picture for when i scroll up]

Comment: Your code doesn't keep the current scroll location, and always draws the rectangle in the same spot. `ScrollWindowEx` doesn't do it for you; all it does is to move the visible pixels on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [How to Scroll a Bitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/scroll-a-bitmap-in-scroll-bars),

> After a window is scrolled, part of its client area is made invalid.
> When processing the WM_PAINT message, an application must repaint the
> invalid region at the bottom of the client area.

See the [Example of Scrolling a Bitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/scroll-a-bitmap-in-scroll-bars#example-of-scrolling-a-bitmap) which uses the `BitBlt` function to copy the appropriate portion of the bitmap to the invalid portion of the client area.

As far as your code is concerned, the second picture and the third picture are a result of the painting of the invalid portion, bottom and top, of the client area.